# How to do a Rails 3 join query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, ruby-on-rails-3, one-to-one

I have the following model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
  has_one :profile
end
```

How would I do and active record query to select profiles of users with a particular role?

Comment: You want a collection of the user profiles, given a role?

Answer (score 0):

`.includes(:relation)` might be useful